# Why do we need re-install tensorflow for each user in server?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tensorflow

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on a supercomputer and it uses for multiple-user using. Let's the name as the suppercomputer is a `serverubuntu`. In the `serverubuntu`, I have install tensorflow-gpu 1.2 as

```
serverubuntu$serverubuntu sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.2
```

After done, I can import the tensorflow when I am typing in the server

```
serverubuntu$serverubuntu python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

Right now, I will add a new user that will remote the server using ssh. Let's call it is `user1`. The `user1` will access the server based on ssh as

```
ssh user1@ip-server
user1@serverubuntu
```

I will try to use tensorflow from terminal of `user1` as

```
user1@serverubuntu python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

However, I got the above error. It is not installed not install tensorflow for `user1`, although `user1` are remoting/using on the server. I tried to go to the server and do the `import tensorflow as tf` in the terminal of server and it works. How could I use tensorflow if I am in the terminal of `user1`?

Comment: It sounds more like `pip` is doing a single-user install instead of a global installation. What is the value of `tf.__file__` after a successful import?

Comment: Sorry for reply late. For user1, it is `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc'`. I did not check it in server because I am in home